# Heredoc: Passing a string with a variable and multiple "$" characters

Tags: string, bash, shell, variables, heredoc

I want to pass a string in a heredoc that contains a variable, and multiple "$" characters.
The command without the heredoc is:

```
FOO='BAR'
echo ${FOO}: '$NOT_A_VARIABLE'
```

The `FOO` variable is correctly substituted and the `'$NOT_A_VARIABLE'` string avoids substitution because it is single quoted. The command returns as expected:

```
BAR: $NOT_A_VARIABLE
```

Now if I do the same inside the heredoc:

```
sh << EOF
   echo ${FOO}: '$NOT_A_VARIABLE'
EOF
```

The output is not what I desired:

```
BAR:
```

It seems, that the `'$NOT_A_VARIABLE'` is substituted even though it is surrounded by single quotes.

I know that this can be avoid by escaping the `$` with a backslash: `\$` but this solution is annoying since there might be multiple `$` characters randomly distributed in the string.

I wonder if there is a smart use of quotes (single/double) or other solutions that might fix it.

Comment: `bash` doesn't parse the heredoc, so it can either expand all variables, or none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of your here document are treated as a double-quoted string, just as if you had written

```
echo "$FOO: '$NOT_A_VARIABLE'" | sh
```

If you want to suppress *all* parameter expansion in the here document, you can quote the delimiter:

```
sh << 'EOF'
    echo ${FOO}: '$NOT_A_VARIABLE'
EOF
```

which will pass

```
echo ${FOO}: '$NOT_A_VARIABLE'
```

as the input to `sh`.

If you only want to suppress a *specific* expansion, escape the `$` just as you would in a double-quoted string.

```
# echo "$FOO: \$NOT_A_VARIABLE" | sh
sh << EOF
   echo ${FOO}: \$NOT_A_VARIABLE
EOF
```

Comment: Actually, the quoted heredoc outputs `BAR: $NOT_A_VARIABLE` if FOO is exported and `: $NOT_A_VARIABLE` otherwise. The quoted heredoc suppresses variable expansion for the **current** shell, but the child `sh` process will evaluate its input as code, repecting the unquoted variable and the single quoted one.

Comment: Reworded the answer to emphasize what the shell's input will be without worrying about the output of the shell.

Comment: Nice. I suppose the OP needs to decide at what level that variable ought to be expanded: in the current shell or the child shell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I was hoping for a solution more elegant and compact than escaping every `$` with `\ `. I will al least escape all `$` instances automatically with `sed 's/\$/\\$/g'`.